# select() from other thread not handle incoming data

Tags: c++, select

I have multithread applications. In one thread I want to waiting for data, and if this datas will not appear through some time, I just close whole application. Function `select()` is runs in another thread and thread is `detach`

A piece sorce some class

```
#define STDIN 0
A::A(){

   runFunction1();
   runFunction2();
   thread listen(&A::isData , this);
   listen.detach();

}

// and function with select

void A::isData{

 struct timeval tv;
    fd_set readfds;
    tv.tv_sec = 50; // wait to 50 seconds
    tv.tv_usec = 500000;
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(STDIN, &readfds);
    for(;;) {

        select(STDIN+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN, &readfds)){
            cout << "I something catch :)" << endl;
            // reset time
        }else{
            cout << "I nothing catch ! By By :(" << endl;
            exit(1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If my program run then I get pid, so I have tryed write to file descriptor some datas in below way:

```
$ cd /proc/somePID/fd
$ echo 1 >> 0
```

Then I should be get info *I something catch :)* but in console IDE I only get *1* , however if time is out I get  *I nothing catch ! By By :(* to console in IDE.

**EDIT: SOLVED**

**@Vladimir Kunschikov** gave me correct tip. Basic on this I show how I do it in **C/C++**

It will be posible send something to process using command *echo* we must create **pipe**. Pipe using function

```
A::A(){
       fd[2]; //two file descriptor for pipes write/read
       pipe(fd); // c function to create pipes
       runFunction1(); 
       runFunction2();
       thread listen(&A::isData , this);
       listen.detach();

    }
```

Then in our proces will create other two new file descriptor as below:

```
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 gru 15 14:02 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 gru 15 14:02 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 gru 15 14:02 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------ 1 user user 64 gru 15 14:02 3 -> pipe:[1335197]
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 gru 15 14:02 4 -> socket:[1340788]
l-wx------ 1 user user 64 gru 15 14:02 5 -> pipe:[1335197]
```

**pipe:[1335197]** is descriptor to read in this proces. Now command echo will be works if we will write some to descriptor **3**. Using is simply:

```
$ cd /proc/PID/fd
$ echo 1 > 3
```

Then we also can using this in `select()` function but descriptor number is 3 so define should be looks like .

```
#define STDIN 3
```

And works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong assumption that writing to the /proc/`pidof application`/fd/0 will put data to the stdin stream of the application. 
Just read answers to this question: [Sending command to java -jar using stdin via /proc/{pid}/fd/0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765035/sending-command-to-java-jar-using-stdin-via-proc-pid-fd-0)